# Unit-Test code coverage not determined correctly

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

When using the `@covers`-annotation, it's not been taken into account when displaying the code coverage.

No matter if I just "cover" the class, or the method, or both.

**Test:**

```php
/**
 * @covers \App\Controller\UserEditController
 */
class UserEditWebTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers ::edit
     */
    public function testEdit():void
    {
        //...
        $this->assertSomething();
    }
}
```

And the tested **Controller:**

```php
namespace App\Controller;

class UserEditController
{
    public function edit() {
        //..
    }

    protected function someOtherFn():void
    {
         //..
    }
}
```

---

Now UnitTest says on **code-coverate output:**

```bash
$ utest --coverage-text

Classes: 23.41% (125/534)   
Methods: 32.75% (1091/3331) 
Lines:   31.58% (4799/15198)

App\Controller\Admin\User\UserEditController
  Methods:   0.00% ( 0/ 2)   Lines:  44.78% ( 30/ 67)
```

---

**Q:** What am I doing wrong?

Why is *`Methods`* on *`0/2`* ?

I also tried removing the `@covers`-Annotation from the test-*method* docblock, or adding the full namespace of the controller before the `::edit` - *nothing* works.

- I cleared the cache of the test-environment

---

## Solution

I found out, that using the `@covers`-annotation is not required at all, actually. If everything is configured correctly, the tested classes, methods and lines should automatically being registered correctly.

In PhpStorm, you can run a "coverage test" which is an xdebug run that shows all code covered.

The annotation was not been taken into account, so I had to actually change my test so that more of the code is truly being tested - e.g. adding tests for each possible case inside a method.

Comment: What lines of code are being executed? Generate html coverage and see what code is being covered.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, i totally missunderstood this. It does not look for the annotation to see whats covered, but the actual classes and methods that are tested.

Comment: @Jonathan : can you please detail the explanation a bit? I am trying to understand but am confused about this. So why is Methods still 0/2 in your example?

Comment: Methods *may be* 0/2 if they are not tested fully, means not each line is being executed. However in practice, one does not need the `@covers` annotation, if everything is configured correctly, it shall automatically register the tested lines, classes and methods. If there is 2 methods, the related percentage can only be 0%, 50% or 100%. Hope this helps. You may try running a "coverage-test" in your IDE to check what's actually tested.